# Translate exception from one type to another

Tags: c++, exception

If have some framework that expects callbacks of a type like

```
void fcn(F& data);
```

It can handle exceptions of type ExF.

In my callback, I am using some third party library that throws exceptions of type ExL. So my callbacks look like

```
void fcn1(F& data)
{
  try
  {
     // call library
  }
  catch(const ExL& ex)
  {
     ExF exf = make_ExF(ex);
     throw exf;
  }
}
```

Now I want to write more callbacks fcn2, fcn3, ... that use the library but do not want to repeat the same try/catch all the time. In particular, maybe I will add another

```
catch(const ExL2& ex)
```

block in the future for several callbacks. I cannot change the code (in particular the exception types) in the framework and the library. How can I avoid repeating the try/catch blocks?

Comment: Write a *function* (or rather a function template) that takes a parameter which is a *function* like `fcn`, and returns a result which is a *function* like `fcn1`. You probanly want to express this with `std::function`.

Comment: Can you please explain this in more detail?

Comment: Got it simplified a bit and posted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a wrapper that does the translation for you.

```
template <typename Func, typename ... Args>
decltype(auto) translate(Func func, Args&&... args)
{
   try {
      return func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
   }
   catch(const ExL& ex) {
       ExF exf = make_ExF(ex);
       throw exf;
   }   
}
```

Now you can `F data; translate(fcn, data)` and it works the same way as `fcn1(data)`.

**EDIT** above code doesn't work as a callback unless one wraps it further (in a lambda for example). Here's an alternative approach:

```
template <typename Res, typename ... Args>
auto
 translate(Res (&func)(Args...)) ->
  std::function<Res(Args...)>
{
   try {
      return [&](Args&& ... args) { return func(std::forward<Args>(args)...); };
   }
   catch(const ExL& ex) {
       ExF exf = make_ExF(ex);
       throw exf;
   }   
}
```

Then your callback is `translate(fcn)`.

Both of these are very general, if you only need to wrap one type of callback, here's an easy way:

```
template<void FCT(F& data)>
void translate(F& data)
{
   try {
        FCT(data);
   }
   catch(const ExL& ex) {
       ExF exf = make_ExF(ex);
       throw exf;
   }   
}
```

and the callback is `translate<fcn>`.

(This is basically the same as your answer but with a standalone function instead of a static member).

Comment: I do not yet understand how the callback should look like in your version, but I got the idea (see seperate answer)

Comment: @HelmutZeisel sorry, got distracted and didn't pay attention to the requirement that it should be a callback. Let me redo my answer...

Answer (score 8):

Take advantage of the fact that while you are in a catch block, you have a "currently handled exception" that you can just `throw;` again. This allows you to move the logic into another function

```
void except_translate() {
  try
  {
     throw;
  }
  catch(const ExL& ex)
  {
     ExF exf = make_ExF(ex);
     throw exf;
  }
}

void fcn1(F& data)
{
  try
  {
     // call library
  }
  catch(...)
  {
     except_translate();
  }
}
```

This technique is known (for googling purposes) as a *Lippincott function*. It centralizes the error translation logic into one place, so you can easily extend that one function with another handler and it will translate it for all functions that use this utility.

Comment: Originally I was expecting that I could completely remove the try/catch blocks by some single line (maybe some kind of RAII object which unfortunately would have to throw in the destructor). Your suggestion still needs a (small) try/catch but is definitely easy to maintain.

Comment: @HelmutZeisel With [function-try-block](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function-try-block), you can remove the enclosing `{}`...

Comment: This saves one line per function, but there are still 7 lines of useless boilerplate per function.

Comment: @n.m. - No solution is going to be without overhead, either in LOC or indirection. This way however, the cost is incurred *only* on the exceptional path, rather than doing indirection *all the time*.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution based on the idea of n.m.:

```
void fcn1_inner(F& data)
{
  // call library, no try/catch
}

template<void FCT(F& data)> struct Wrapper
{
  static void FN(F& data)
  {
     try
     {
        FCT(data);
     }
     catch(const ExL& ex)
     {
       ExF exf = make_ExF(ex);
       throw exf;
     }
  }
};
```

The callback is now

```
Wrapper<fcn1_inner>::FN
```

Comment: The nice thing about C++ is that you can merge run-time and compile-time code reuse into impressive results. For instance, here's how you can use n.m's approach along with mine to cut both LOC *and* the size of generated exception handling code per function https://godbolt.org/z/DkrUWN